# direction of connection between points v1, v2 on a circle, with obstacles (blocking interval [s, e])

Tags: math, geometry, computational-geometry

i know the title seems bad - please feel free to specify. I can not come up with a better title.

All points are stated in polar coordinates relative to the circle center. Two points (**v1, v2, s, e**) lay on a circle edge. As shown in the image, **s** & **e** are the pink points, **s** = blocked_arc_start_angle, **e** = blocked_arc_end_angle.

[image]

Problem:
How do i check which direction on the circle is not blocked? With direction i mean clockwise (CW, math negative) or counter clockwise (CCW, math positive).

**all angles are normalized and have a range of [-PI, PI]**

I tried a lot of if-else case checks but due to the range of atan2 i have problems. Is there a easy simple way?
Any ideas?
regards!

**I am still looking for a better solution!!! nobady likes many if-else calls...***
**Ugly Answer:**
I thought about all cases which can occur, you can easily split by imagining the rage of the angle space:

```
1st case - obstacle/blocked arc/interval is not overlapping:
-Pi                                  PI
|-------------S::::::::E-------------|

2nd case - obstacle/blocked arc/interval is overlapping:
-Pi                                  PI
|::::E--------------------------S::::|
```

and so on...
**important:** check in before hand if a point lays inside the blocked interval:

```
# no point is inside of a blocked arc
if m.point_inside_arc(v1.location, arc) or m.point_inside_arc(v2.location, arc):
    return False
```

Here is some pseudo code. Hopefully this helps some one.

```
if arc.start_angle < arc.end_angle:
    if angle_v1 < angle_v2 < arc.start_angle or arc.end_angle < angle_v1 < angle_v2:
        # |----V1---V2----S::::::::E----(V1---V2)----|
        math_negative = False
    elif angle_v2 < angle_v1 < arc.start_angle or arc.end_angle < angle_v2 < angle_v1:
        # |----V2---V1----S::::::::E----(V2---V1)----|
        math_positive = False
    elif angle_v1 < arc.start_angle and arc.end_angle < angle_v2:
        # |----V1---------S::::::::E---------V2----|
        math_positive = False
    elif angle_v2 < arc.start_angle and arc.end_angle < angle_v1:
        # |----V2---------S::::::::E---------V1----|
        math_negative = False
else:
    # |::::E-------------------------S::::|
    if angle_v1 < angle_v2:
       math_negative = False
    else:
       math_positive = False
```

Comment: Which programming environment are you using that has "a range of [0, 2*PI], -> atan2(y,x)"? [Most environments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) have a range of (-PI, PI] for atan2. Also, your question is not clear. What do you mean by "what direction" since there are infinitely many such directions? Do you just want a representation of the arc between p1 and p2 that includes v1 and v2? Finally, could you show one of your attempts on the question and explain what is wrong with that attempt?

Comment: ohh, maybe the range of atan2 was the problem. I will check that just now! Thank you for statements regarding the scope for interpretation of my words. I tried to refine that

Comment: You don't tell us the ranges of s and e nor how you want the answer to be given.

Comment: I refined the question again. I want just the direction (CW or CCW)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let c to be the center of the circle. Then if you calculate:

```
dot = DotProduct( p1 - c, p2 - c )
```

All points v for which both conditions are true:

```
DotProduct( v - c, p1 - c ) > dot
DotProduct( v - c, p2 - c ) > dot
```

will be in the blocked area

In order to know the direction you can use also dot product. As dot product is the cos of the angle between vectors (supposing both vectors are unitary), you can calculate for each point p1 and p2 the angle alpha:

cos( alpha ) = DotProduct( vector( 1, 0 ), ( p1 - c ).normalized );

After getting alpha, you must use the value of component y of ( p1 - c ).

If it is negative, then add 180 degrees to alpha.

Comment: I dont want to check if points are inside of the blocked arc. I want to know which direction is blocked. Direction: clockwise or counter clockwise. Maybe i can achieve that with your answer. Give me a hint :)

Comment: I've edited my answer to give you a hint to calculate angles. The response can be simplified as the dot product with vector=(1,0) is just the x component of p1-c. But the general idea is in the response

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the two angles modulo 2π. Then if e < s, the circle is uncovered from 0 to s and from e to 2π; otherwise, the circle is uncovered from s to e.